# If column J in sheet 1 matches column C in sheet 2, print whats in sheet 2 column B into Sheet 1 column L

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

Sorry for the long title. As it states I am trying to find matches between two columns in separate sheets. Sheet 1 is the spreadsheet I am trying to automate. Sheet 2 is a set list of categories, and their related business process.

**Looking for an IF/Vlookup statement:**

*If The category in Sheet 1 data (column J) matches one of the categories in the list on sheet 2 (column C). I want to print what is in column B on sheet 2, which is the affected business of that particular category, into Column L on sheet 1.*

I tried to add images but I am too new. Sorry.

I've tried nested IFs and If/Vlookups and I cant seem to get it to print what I want. If you need more info I would be glad to provide it.

Comment: I actually just figured it out. In my VLOOKUP i needed to specify which range and give it a name...Simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(J1,Sheet2!C:C,0)),"")
```

VLOOKUP will not work where trying to use ColumnC to get a value in ColumnB - it only looks to the right so the columns might be re-arranged for VLOOKUP to work by using ColumnB to get a value in ColumnC.